# Solution required to create Regex pattern

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am developing a windows application in C#. I have been searching for the solution to my problem in creating a Regex pattern. I want to create a Regex pattern matching the either of the following strings:

```
XD=(111111) XT=(   588.466)m3 YT=(      .246)m3 G=( 3.6)V N=(X0000000000) M=(Y0000000000) O=(Z0000000000) Date=(06.01.01)Time=(00:54:55) Q=(       .00)m3/hr

XD=(111   ) XT=(   588.466)m3 YT=(      .009)m3 G=( 3.6)V N=(X0000000000) M=(Y0000000000) O=(Z0000000000) Date=(06.01.01)Time=(00:54:55) Q=(       .00)m3/hr
```

The specific requirement is that I need all the values from the above given string which is a collection of key/value pairs. Also, would like to know the right approach (in terms of efficiency and performance) out of the two...Regex pattern matching or substring, for the above problem.

Thank you all in advance and let me know, if more details are required.

Comment: Do you also need to match the units (`m3/hr` etc.)?

Comment: Yes, I do need the match the units in the string.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know C#, so there probably is a better way to build a key/value array. I constructed a regex and handed it to [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) which generated the following code snippet:

```
StringCollection keyList = new StringCollection();
StringCollection valueList = new StringCollection();
StringCollection unitList = new StringCollection();
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(
        @"(?<key>\b\w+)      # Match an alphanumeric identifier
        \s*=\s*              # Match a = (optionally surrounded by whitespace)
        \(                   # Match a (
        \s*                  # Match optional whitespace
        (?<value>[^()]+)     # Match the value string (anything except parens)
        \)                   # Match a )
        (?<unit>[^\s=]+      # Match an optional unit (anything except = or space)
        \b                   # which must end at a word boundary
        (?!\s*=)             # and not be an identifier (i. e. followed by =)
        )?                   # and is optional, as mentioned.", 
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResult.Success) {
        keyList.Add(matchResult.Groups["key"].Value);
        valueList.Add(matchResult.Groups["value"].Value);
        unitList.Add(matchResult.Groups["unit"].Value);
        matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
    }
```

Comment: Dear Tim,
Thank you very much. Your solution did work for all the combinations of values in the source string. Appreciate your help and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex re=new Regex(@"(\w+)\=\(([\d\s\.]+)\)");
MatchCollection m=re.Matches(s);
```

- `m[0].Groups` will have `{ XD=(111111), XD, 111111 }`
- `m[1].Groups` will have `{ XT=(   588.466), XT,    588.466 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] rows = { "XD=(111111) XT=(   588.466)m3 YT=(      .246)m3 G=( 3.6)V N=(X0000000000) M=(Y0000000000) O=(Z0000000000) Date=(06.01.01)Time=(00:54:55)      Q=(       .00)m3/hr", 
  "XD=(111   ) XT=(   588.466)m3 YT=(      .009)m3 G=( 3.6)V N=(X0000000000) M=(Y0000000000) O=(Z0000000000) Date=(06.01.01)Time=(00:54:55) Q=(       .00)m3/hr" };

foreach (String s in rows) {

    MatchCollection Pair = Regex.Matches(s, @"
        (\S+)         # Match all non-whitespace before the = and store it in group 1
        =             # Match the =
        (\([^)]+\S+)  # Match the part in brackets and following non-whitespace after the = and store it in group 2
       ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    foreach (Match item in Pair) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1] + " => " + item.Groups[2]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to extract the units also then use this regex

```
@"(\S+)=(\([^)]+(\S+))
```

I added a set of brackets around it, then you will find the unit in `item.Groups[3]`

Comment: Apologies but how can I extract the units separately such as m3, V, m3/hr, as I will be storing all the extracted values in DB and for all units in the source string (in above case 4), there are separate columns, respectively. Thank you once again for your help.